# What exactly happens when running ng build --prod?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

A client who is using an **old Firefox version** (50.1.0) said that the angular application my company developed is **not loading**.

After some investigation, I found the culprit: ng build --prod

According to [angular-cli's github doc](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#--dev-vs---prod-builds) and [Angular's official doc](https://angular.io/guide/deployment), ng build --prod is a **meta flag** for

```
--aot --environment=prod --output-hashing=all --sourcemaps=false --extract-css=true --named-chunks=false --build-optimizer=true
```

This cannot be the entire truth because when using ng build --prod my app does not load on Firefox 50.1.0, **but when using all flags combined, it works**.

**My question: What additional flags does --prod add ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is `--target=production`

When used, it seems to cause a problem with earlier Firefox versions. See [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9340)

Answer (score 2):

This is everything that the production flag uses:

```
- Ahead-of-Time (AOT) Compilation: pre-compiles Angular component templates.
- Production mode: deploys the production environment which enables production mode.
- Bundling: concatenates your many application and library files into a few bundles.
- Minification: removes excess whitespace, comments, and optional tokens.
- Uglification: rewrites code to use short, cryptic variable and function names.
- Dead code elimination: removes unreferenced modules and much unused code.
```

Comment: Yes I know the official docs, but what flags are behind this ?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience ng build --prod not work as accepted.
Use "ng build --prod --env=prod" instead.
Its work for me.

---- EDIT -----
When using ng build --prod  its take variables from environment.prod.ts.

Comment: On GitHub the doc says "# these are equivalent". I will try if there is a difference.

Comment: So I tried and I am getting the same error as with --prod. So as far as this goes, they are equivalent

Comment: The error is irrelevant, it's a "TypeError" in a .js file. What I want to know is how --prod affects the build :)

Comment: Do you have file environments/environment.prod.ts ?
Its take variables from there like server url etc..

Comment: I do not use it.